# Only break on breakpoints in MacGDBp?

Tags: php, macos, debugging, gdb, xdebug

MacGDBp has a setting called "Break on first line of execution", which I turned off.. but it doesn't seem to do anything. It still catches and breaks every single query, making it a useless app to use.

Does anyone use MacGDBp that knows a way around this? I'd love to make use of it, but at this point it's not worth it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that this could be much more involved, but that sounds like what happens when you step through the code.

Which button are you clicking? The Continue button should jump to the next breakpoint.

I grabbed this from:
[Debugging your PHP Code: XDebug on MAMP with TextMate and MacGDBp Support](http://technosophos.com/content/debugging-your-php-code-xdebug-mamp-textmate-and-macgdbp-support)

[image: xdebug macgdbp buttons]

From left to right, the buttons are:

Step into: Clicking this will advance the debugger one step and, if necessary, go "into" the function, class, file, etc. By clicking this button repeatedly, you can step through every part of the process.

Step out: This will move up a level. For example, if you are mid-way through a function and you step out, the debugger will advance to the next part of the code, skipping the remainder of the function.

Step Over (Skip): This will skip examining the next step. For example, if the current line is pointing to a function, and you do not want to see the function execute, you can skip it with this button. Clicking this will simply advance to the next line in the current scope.

Continue (Play): Continue execution until either the next breakpoint or the end of the script.

Reset: Remove the current debugging session and wait for the next request from the server.

Using these buttons, you can navigate through the execution of a script. While this will give you a detailed step-by-step analysis of a program as it executes, it can often be overkill. More often, you will want to analyze just a small part of your script. That is best accomplished with breakpoints.

A breakpoint is a marker that tells the debugger to pause when the location is reached. Using breakpoints, you can set the debugger to play through most of the code, pausing only when it gets to the portion of interest.

**EDIT: February 26, 2012**

Hi Naatan,

You could take a look at the xdebug logs by adding this line to your php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
```

You can determine if MacGDBp is sending any breakpoints and if it's sending a run command or a  step_into command.

Here is what I see for six different scenarios. I stripped out most of the data as it took a lot of space, let me know if you need to see data for a specific line.

**1) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = OFF AND NO BREAKPOINTS**

```
Log opened at 2012-02-26 22:27:47
-> <init

<- feature_set -i 2859 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2860 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2861 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response

<- feature_get -i 2862 -n max_data
-> <response

<- eval -i 2863 --
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="2863"><property address=

<- run -i 2864
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2864" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

**2) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = ON AND NO BREAKPOINTS**

```
  Log opened at 2012-02-26 22:35:39
  -> <init

  <- feature_set -i 2913 -n show_hidden -v 1
  -> <response

  <- feature_set -i 2914 -n max_depth -v 3
  -> <response

  <- feature_set -i 2915 -n max_children -v 30
  -> <response

  <- feature_get -i 2916 -n max_data
  -> <response

  <- eval -i 2917 --
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="2917"><property address=

  // 2a) STEP INTO CALLED BECAUSE "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" IS TURNED ON
  <- step_into -i 2918
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="2918" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

  <- stack_get -i 2919
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="2919"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

  <- context_names -i 2920
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="2920"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

  <- context_get -i 2921 -c 0
  -> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

  <- context_get -i 2922 -c 1
  -> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

  // 2b) CLICK CONTINUE
  <- run -i 2923
  -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2923" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

**3) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = ON, WITH BREAKPOINT ON FIRST LINE**

```
Log opened at 2012-02-26 22:41:56
-> <init

<- feature_set -i 2936 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2937 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2938 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response

<- feature_get -i 2939 -n max_data
-> <response

// 3a) LISTS ALL BREAKPOINTS THAT ARE SET
<- breakpoint_set -i 2940 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/application/html/index.php -n 2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="2940" state="enabled" id="179940003"></response>

<- eval -i 2941 --
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="2941"><property address=

// 3b) STEP INTO CALLED BECAUSE "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = ON
<- step_into -i 2942
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="2942" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 2943
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="2943"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 2944
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="2944"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 2945 -c 0
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

<- context_get -i 2946 -c 1
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

// 3c) CLICK CONTINUE
<- run -i 2947
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2949" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

**4) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = ON, WITH BREAKPOINT ON LINE 10**

```
Log opened at 2012-02-27 00:29:26
-> <init

<- feature_set -i 3023 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 3024 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 3025 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response

<- feature_get -i 3026 -n max_data
-> <response

// 4a) LISTS ALL BREAKPOINTS THAT ARE SET
<- breakpoint_set -i 3027 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/application/html/index.php -n 10
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3027" state="enabled" id="180020001"></response>

<- eval -i 3028 --
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="3028"><property address=

// 4b) STEP INTO CALLED BECAUSE "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = ON
<- step_into -i 3029
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="3029" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 3030
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="3030"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 3031
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="3031"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 3032 -c 0
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

<- context_get -i 3033 -c 1
  -> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

// 4c) CLICK CONTINUE - GOES TO BREAKPOINT ON LINE 10
<- run -i 3034
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="3034" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="10"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 3035
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="3035"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="10"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 3036
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="3036"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 3037 -c 0
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

<- context_get -i 3038 -c 1
  -> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

// 4d) CLICK CONTINUE
<- run -i 3039
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2864" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

**5) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = OFF, WITH BREAKPOINT ON FIRST LINE**

```
Log opened at 2012-02-26 22:49:46
-> <init

<- feature_set -i 2962 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2963 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 2964 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response

<- feature_get -i 2965 -n max_data
-> <response

// 5a) LISTS ALL BREAKPOINTS THAT ARE SET
<- breakpoint_set -i 2966 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/application/html/index.php -n 2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="2966" state="enabled" id="180160005"></response>

<- eval -i 2967 --
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="2967"><property address="140734566267920" type="string" size="77" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cDovL2RldmVsb3BtZW50Lm1hcmluYXMuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocD9YREVCVUdfU0VTU0lPTl9TVEFSVD1uZXRiZWFucy14ZGVidWc=]]></property></response>

<- run -i 2968
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2968" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 2969
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="2969"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 2970
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="2970"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 2971 -c 0
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

<- context_get -i 2972 -c 1
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

// 5b) CLICK CONTINUE
<- run -i 2973
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2973" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

**6) "BREAK ON FIRST LINE OF EXECUTION" = OFF, WITH BREAKPOINT ON LINE 10**

```
Log opened at 2012-02-27 00:46:23
-> <init

<- feature_set -i 3052 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 3053 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response

<- feature_set -i 3054 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response

<- feature_get -i 3055 -n max_data
-> <response

// 6a) LISTS ALL BREAKPOINTS THAT ARE SET
<- breakpoint_set -i 3056 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/application/html/index.php -n 10
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3056" state="enabled" id="179990006"></response>

<- eval -i 3057 --
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="3057"><property address="140734566267920" type="string" size="77" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cDovL2RldmVsb3BtZW50Lm1hcmluYXMuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocD9YREVCVUdfU0VTU0lPTl9TVEFSVD1uZXRiZWFucy14ZGVidWc=]]></property></response>

<- run -i 3058
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="3058" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="10"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 3059
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="3059"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/application/html/index.php" lineno="10"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 3060
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="3060"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 3061 -c 0
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Locals" VARIABLES

<- context_get -i 3062 -c 1
-> <response xmlns= // SHOWS "Superglobals" VARIABLES

// 6b) CLICK CONTINUE
<- run -i 3063
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="3063" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

Be Well,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, I am familiar with how to use a debugger. My problem is that MacGDBp always breaks on the first line of execution no matter what, even though I have turned that setting off. I'm not sure whether it's a problem with the program or with xDebug.

Comment: Hi Naatan, I added some info about what the log entries for xdebug look like.

Comment: Hi Naatan, A few more thoughts. The source code for MacGDBp is available, I took a look at it and you could change that setting to off and compile it if you have the xcode ide (it's a free download from the mac app store). Another option would be to use the mac version of the netbeans ide. I use the windows version and it works well with xdebug.

Comment: Woah, impressive work Joe, I will definitely look into it and report back if I find a solution. I currently use Komodo IDE for debugging but I use Sublime Text 2 as my main IDE, so using a lightweight program for debugging like MacDBGp would be far more ideal. By the way, what did you use to log those xDebug queries? I've been researching building an xDebug client and being able to log queries like that would be quite useful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Naatan, You can add xdebug.remote_log=PATH/FILE_NAME to your php.ini file where you added the other xdebug settings. My server is linux, so I can look at the log with the "tail" command while in debug mode to watch the log as it updates.

Comment: Hi Naatan, I ran into a bug in xdebug last night (exits when it encounters mysqli_init). Although that's not your problem, it might be worth trying a different version of xdebug. With only two people reporting your problem to the MacGDBp bug tracker it could be that the problem lies elsewhere. Also, take a look at the xdebug.trace_output_dir and the other trace settings. I played around with them and you get the trace log output every time a page loads, so it's not affected by using a debugging client.That log was more helpful in finding the mysqli_init bug than the remote_log file.

Comment: I tried the Komodo xdebug version as well as the one that comes with MAMP, both have the same problem unfortunately. I also tried playing around in the source to see if I could locate the problem but that did not turn up anything (didn't help that I know nothing about xcode :)). I'm also very surprised that there aren't more people reporting this issue. I've tried MacGDBp multiple times on various installs and have ALWAYS had this problem. Very frustrating.

Comment: I found a small fork on github which adds a "Continue to first breakpoint" settings. Unfortunately this doesn't solve anything as it seems like MacGDBp is simply bugged out altogether when sending responses. No matter if I click continue or not it will just hang there and do nothing. In the connection log I only see the following 2 responses: "run -i 1" and "stop -i 2", that's without me doing any sort of interaction, just letting it run. I've tried all xdebug versions from 2.0 to 2.2.

Comment: Finally found something. It turns out MacGDBp cannot handle traffic that is gzip encoded, which in my case it was. This was the main problem that made it appear as if it was just failing at the first line. After disabling gzip it goes through all the way, but another problem arises. MacGDBp falls flat out on the floor when you are running several queries simultaneously, which is all the time for me as the page I'm loading has scripts in it that are generated with PHP. This means you have to be incredibly lucky to get all of them to run through MacGDBp without one of them failing. Gah!

Comment: I'm not clear about how multiple queries are run simultaneously. What do you mean by "query"? Database query, call to a function, includes of files containing PHP code, something else? Each of these  items needs to complete before the next one is started. Is it a problem where the HTML for the page is being generated and output in pieces rather than as a complete page? That could be fixed using output buffering, you could call ob_start() before anything is output and ob_get_flush() at the end of the page. Here's the control functions reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: By query I just mean a HTTP query / request. Sorry for the confusion. I've also found by now that it's not actually the simultaneous http requests that are causing it to hang, it just seems to happen randomly. I've also found that small scripts usually go through without any sort of hickups, while large ones randomly seem to hang, with the large ones simply disabling the line that outputs to the browser (ie. echo) makes the script run without problem. But with the output line enabled it only randomly hangs about 40% of the time. Very weird..

Comment: I've marked this question as resolved (as the original question was essentially answered) and updated the bug report on the MacGDBp website (http://www.bluestatic.org/bugs/showreport.php?bugid=226) so as not to go completely off-topic here on StackOverflow. Thanks for all your help Jon, if you happen to think of anything else please let me know, I much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Once anything is sent to the browser, no more headers can be sent without causing problems, maybe with the added communication between MacGDBp and xDebug there are times when additional header info needs to be sent? Do you collect all of you HTML output in a variable and only echo the data out at the end of the page? My pages output everything at the end, so I don't have the situation of HTML being output sporadically as the code is running. Only thing I can think of that might help is putting the ob_start() in your header file before anything is output and an ob_get_XXX() at the very end.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already using ob streams as well, so that doesn't seem to be it. I also don't think xdebug or MacGDBp use http headers. Only a cookie for session control AFAIK.